# get always difference in dates rounded when possible , when not just give the lowest date dimension

Tags: postgresql

In postgres in my timezone as of now when I issue the following statement :

`select format('%s days','2023-04-05'::date - '2023-04-01'::date)`

4 days

This `select format('%s days','2024-04-05'::date - '2023-04-01'::date)` gives me:

370 days

And this select `format('%s days','2023-05-05'::date - '2023-04-01'::date)`:

34 days

What I would like to have is some form of rounding for the days , but only when they reach a month or a year. So as to make the result as:

```
 4 days
1 year and 5 days (because a years has 365 days + 5 days extra)
1 month and 4 days (because this month has 30 days + 4 days extra)
```

Comment: Calculate it as an interval? `justify_interval('2024-04-05'::timestamp - '2023-04-01'::timestamp)`

Comment: A date minus a date returns an integer. Use justify_interval if you want something different

Comment: Actually  `select '360 days'::interval = '1 year'::interval; t` and `select '365 days'::interval = '1 year'::interval; f`. As `12 months * 30 days = 360 days`.